# Transform in CDC with Debezium + Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, ksqldb

When im doing my CDC with Debezium+kafka+postgres+elasticsearch i need to transform one column.

In elasticsearch i have a this json:

```
   {"name": "Julia", "store":"Americanas"}
```

And moving to postgres i want to transform my store data to :

```
    {"name":"Julia", "store":"WallMart"}
```

How can i do that?

In my searchs i found SMT, but i dont find who SMT i can apply to do this update.
And i found stream processing with Spark,ksql and alpakka, but i dont know if they can solve my problem.

Comment: So you want to replace any instance in the `store` field of `Americanas` with `Wallmart`? Or is it more complicated than than?

Comment: For beginningi its only this

Comment: @LuanCarvalho You can probably take a look at `https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/TimestampConverter.java` as that is an SMT for converting timestamp fields between differing formats.  You could use that as a basis for translating `Americanas` to `WallMart` fairly easily.

Comment: I really can use this, thank you a lot !
But do you know another way to solve that problem? im looking for the best options for me and my team !

Comment: SMTs are the best way to transform data Debezium captures from the tx log into a form that subscribers to your topic need.